# OpenGL Post Processing using Power of Two Textures

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl, shader

I am trying to do some post processing in OpenGL ES, so I decided to use power of two texture sizes just to be safe. However, the source image is rectangular and does not exactly fit in a PoT texture, so I downscale and draw it into a Frame Buffer (without stretching, I will get to it later) like in this picture:
[image]

So there is a gap/empty area in the texture which is black or whatever color I clear it to. This then becomes the source texture I use, and I ping pong it numerous times to apply an effect. I tried to outline the problem which I think I will face in the picture. Basically the pixels on the edge will sample from the empty area when I use a shader like blur or bloom that samples from neighboring pixels. If I used a npot texture or stretched it, CLAMP_TO_EDGE would save me from this, but I can't wrap my head around how to do it in my case. Here are some ideas I've come up with:

- Stretch the image to fill the whole texture: I feel some shaders like edge detection etc. could cause an imbalance in the stretched and non-stretched axes in the final image. I want this to work for all types of shaders. Am I wrong in this assumption?
- Try to manually emulate CAMP_TO_EDGE by filling the empty area with the edge colors of the source image: Feels cumbersome and has to be done every ping pong step.
- Clamp the texture coordinates in the fragment shader (e.g. horizontal 0.7 is max): I think this would be heavy in the shader, especially so when sampling multiple coordinates.

So, is there any way I can do this efficiently, like setting a texture coord as the edge or something? I know NPoT textures would make this a whole lot easier but I want to explore my options with PoT first. And since even Desktop GPUs were not NPoT friendly in the beginning, I feel like this has to be an already solved problem and there must exist some best practices for this.

Comment: I'm not sure if the coordinate clamping is as expensive as you might think, especially when compared to the actual texture fetch. However, if you use the bilinear filtering and no weird anisotropy, evey pass will just read data from 1px beyond the border, so basically, if you know the number of passes beforehand, you could repeat the image data for `n` pixels initially, and then just work on `n-1`  to `0` extra pixels in each subsequent pass.

Comment: Both your first and third options would yield pretty good performance results. Additionally, if you know your max horizontal coord would be 0.7, you could simply change your horiz UV values to fit between the `[0.0, 0.7]` range so you woldn't need to perform any clamping in your frag shader.

Comment: @derhass the problem is there are some shaders I'm planning to use that may potentially read very far into the empty area (some sort of elongate/star trail shader). I want to find a method that is generic rather than a workaround for a few specific shaders that I'll be using.

Comment: @Marquizzo How do I clamp my uvs without clamping explicitly in the shader though? I mean assume that I textured a quad with horizontal uvs from 0.0 to 0.7 and I am using a blur kernel that samples n neighboring pixels. When the shader runs for a border pixel at 0.7, will it not sample from coordinates exceeding 0.7? I think it will.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I missed the part where you would need blurring, which does sample neighboring fragments. That being said, `clamp()` is a very inexpensive function and you shouldn't be afraid to use it. In fact, performing a Gaussian blur is much more computationally expensive than simply clamping a UV value.

Comment: @Marquizzo I will try clamping in the shader unless another more straightforward solution comes up, it looks like I am overestimating its performance cost based on current feedback. Actually I wish I had a definitive answer on whether streching an image, running a shader and stretching back to original aspect ratio would break down for some image processing algorithms / shaders. If not, it would be a super easy and clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate clamp to edge when generating the POT version of the texture.

When generating the POT framebuffer rather than just rendering the part of the framebuffer which matches the original texture, render something slightly oversized (e.g. enough additional pixels to cover your filter kernel width). If you render this using `CLAMP_TO_EDGE` on the original NPOT texture read you make you'll simply extend the edge of the original texture into your kernel's overspill region.

You can then read this as normal with the coordinate range you were planning and it should just work as if you were reading the original texture with `CLAMP_TO_EDGE` applied. Even though clamp is cheap, I would expect this to be cheaper ...

Comment: The problem is the POT version is then used for a multipass effect. I can emulate CLAMP_TO_EDGE for the first copy, but as I ping-pong this around and modify it, let's say with a blur shader, assuming I only render on the relevant part of the frame buffer; the edge part is no longer accurate for my texture, it's the edge from the original image.

Comment: In that case I guess you're stuck with using `clamp()` on the original coordinate. You might avoid most of the additional cost by rendering two draw calls - one quad which covers the part which doesn't need `clamp()` and one which does. At least then you're only paying the extra cost when you need it.